# Dynamic navigation with parameter passing in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, parameter-passing

I want to pass the "title" parameter in the following listing dynamicaly to another jsf Facelet, depending on the selection of the selectOneMenu. My first approach looks like this:

```html
<h:form id="form">

    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{exerciseEditorBean.selectedExerciseType}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Multiple Choice Exercise" itemValue="MultipleChoiceExercise" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Vocabulary Test" itemValue="VocabularyTest" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputText value="Enter Title of your Exercise: " />  
    <h:inputText id="title" value="#{exerciseEditorBean.exerciseTitle}" />

    <h:commandButton value="Next" action="#{exerciseEditorBean.openEditor()}" />

</h:form>
```

The ExerciseEditorBean is ViewScoped.

The openEditor() function then decides by the selectedExerciseType attribute which Facelet to show next and returns something like "multipleChoiceEditor.xhtml". 
How can I now pass the titel attribute to this Facelet?

Comment: JSF is designed for navigation based on HTTP post requests. This means that when you navigate to a page, parameters are also passed in this way. I very much dislike that fact since it also disallows bookmarking. I prefer to navigate based on get requests with parameterized URLs. IMO an URL should look like `/editor/multiplechoice` instead of `/editor.xhtml` or `/editor.xhtml?type=multiplechoice`. If you're interested, take a look at PrettyFaces. ;-)

Comment: @siebz0r, you can bookmark URLs generated with `<h:button/>` or `<h:link/>` and conveniently pass params with `includeViewParams=true` on either of them. They both generate GETs as against the stock POST with the commandXXX components

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: @kolossus Whether this is a pretty solution is up for debate ;-)

Comment: In JSF, the only servlet is the `FacesServlet`. You perhaps meant to say "Facelet" everytime you (mis)typed "servelet".

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the correction. I'm sorry, I'm new to JSF and sometimes I mess up the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use the f:ViewParam in the target servelet, which works well except, that "multipleChoiceEditor.xhtml?includeViewParams=true" does not work, but this is another issue. Thanks for the discussion!